# SSRS reports - How to draw line between the group as marked in red color in the picture

Tags: reporting-services, report

[image: SSRS Report with line between the group]

SSRS Report with line between the group

@Chris Latta, I updated the border style for the details row still no line between the group. Please find the report design view & result in images
[image: Report designview][image: Result view]

Answer (score 2):

Select the entire detail row and add this expression to the BorderStyle-Top property:

```
=IIF((Previous(Fields!Refno.Value) <> Fields!Refno.Value), 
    "Solid",
    "None")
```

Comment: I have edited with the result rendered based on your suggestion. still no luck. any help would be greatly appriciated.

Comment: You have the group footer selected - the expression needs to be on the Detail row (that is, the row above the row it is on in your picture)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a ranking number in sql then use the dense rank number as a group level in ssrs, this will create the automatic breaking.  Next, add top and bottom borders for the totaling cell.

declare @Tmp as table([Ref. No.] varchar(20), [Order] varchar(20),[Req. Date] date, [Item Number] varchar(20), [Buyer] varchar(1),
[Short Hnd] int)

```
insert into @Tmp(
[Ref. No.], [Order],[Req. Date] , [Item Number] , [Buyer] ,
[Short Hnd] 
)
values(
'KIT 09271','M158460','5/27/21','10191149','P',1),
('KIT 09271','M158460','5/27/21','10202633','',1),
('MSN09253','M159320','7/30/21','615218','P',2),
('MSN09253','M159320','7/30/21','623202','T',4),
('MSN09271','M159260','7/21/21','10202825','P',1),
('MSN09271','M159260','7/21/21','10203267','',1)

select DENSE_RANK() over(order by [Ref. No.]) Rank,* from @Tmp
```

output:

```
Rank    Ref. No.    Order   Req. Date   Item Number Buyer   Short Hnd
1   KIT 09271   M158460 2021-05-27  10191149    P   1
1   KIT 09271   M158460 2021-05-27  10202633        1
2   MSN09253    M159320 2021-07-30  615218  P   2
2   MSN09253    M159320 2021-07-30  623202  T   4
3   MSN09271    M159260 2021-07-21  10202825    P   1
3   MSN09271    M159260 2021-07-21  10203267        1
```

now you can use ssrs grouping totals to do your subtotalling.